# Regex Pattern with {^ and ^}

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a pattern that matches `{^xyz^}` as bellow,

```
@"\b\{\^\S*\^\}\b
```

But I am not getting success and wondering what is problem with my pattern.

Comment: because I want to get the string between {^ and ^}.... for a example if string is {^fristname^}... I want to get 'firstname'.

Comment: What tools are you using to match(reason is you need to escape the `\\`)? There is quote infront of your re!

Comment: sorry I want to highlight firstname that is why I placed single quotes in my reply

Comment: You can use: `@"\{\^([^}]*)\^\}"` and extract captured group #1 for your string.

Comment: @anubhava : its working thank you

Comment: @dula, beware that if your inside string has a `}`, that regex won't work. And it will also capture the string if it has a space (even new line characters).

Comment: @dula, can you be so kind to take a look at the messages you have here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
@"\{\^([^}]*)\^\}"
```

and extract captured group #1 for your string.

- Use a captured group to get the substring you want to extract from a larger match.
- Word boundaries or `\b` won't work here because `{` and `}` are non-word characters.
- Use of negated character class `[^}]*` is more efficient and accurate than greedy `\S*`.

Comment: Not sure if it's a possible string, but your regex won't match `{^curly{brace}inside^}.`.

Comment: See, we can always invent an input that will cause issues with a given regex but key is whether it is a valid input as per OP or now.

Comment: The issue is you assumed there won't be closing curly brackets in that string, I don't know why. ;)

Comment: And you assumed there is no space because your regex won't match `{^ab cd^}` so I suggest please re-read my 1st comment that we can always invent an input....

Comment: But that's what dula used, so that's probably what is needed; I'm not making up anything. This regex will even capture strings with line feed characters in it. I think it's too risky and different to what OP is attempting to do.

Comment: What he had in question didn't work and what I suggested in comments below the question worked for him as per his comment below my suggested solution. I will let OP provide more details before editing my solution (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `\{\^(\S*?)\^\}`. This way you are capturing the contents between the carets and curly brackets. The `?` is to make the `*` quantifier lazy, so it matches as little characters as possible (in order to prevent matching the beginning of one block until the end of another block in the same line).

With those `\b` you need a word-type character right before and after the curly braces for the regex to match. Is that really a requirement? Or can there be a space?